# Is non-stationarity an issue in this setting?

Tags: multiple-regression, stationarity, trend, differencing, spurious-correlation

I am trying to model the development of European spot prices of gas. My purpose is to explain what has caused past movements in the gas price, rather than forecasting future gas prices.

Naturally, this data follows a seasonal pattern, which causes the series to be non-stationary. Is this necessarily an issue in the model? In my university courses, I learnt that first differencing should be performed to address the non-stationarity of the data. However, would it not be sufficient to include the variable HDD (heating degree days: a measure of how cold the temperature was on a given day) in the model, which captures this seasonality? Of course, you could argue that there may be a spurious regression but intuitively you can argue why this variable should capture all seasonality right?

Apart from the seasonality, I am also concerned about the trend of increasing gas prices throughout 2022. I try to explain this based on several variables, such as a variable related to (reduced) imports from Russia. Is this also at risk of being a spurious regression? If so, then first differencing should be applied to account for this?

Hopefully, someone can help me out!